# How can I determine if a value is in a Perl array?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I'm using this small snippet to determine whether or not a URL is currently being stored in an array:

```
if( $self->{_local} eq "true" && ! grep {m|^$new_href?$|} @m_href_array ) {
    push( @m_href_array, $new_href );
    push( @href_array, $new_href );
}
```

It seems to work but then my code throws an error saying:

`Sequence (?$...) not implemented in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^javascript:SearchGo(?$ <-- HERE / at C:/Perl/site/lib/ACTC.pm line 152, <> line 1.`

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When searching for a string in an array, you can just use `eq`, rather than a regular expression:

```
grep { $_ eq $new_href } @m_href_array
```

However, if you really do need to use a regular expression (for example you are searching for a string matching a substring in the array, you should *always* quote the string, so that embedded special characters in your string do not have undesired effects:

```
grep { /\Q$substr\Esomething_else/ } @array
```

Moreover, if all you care about is whether the value is there, *somewhere*, you can short-circuit as soon as you've found a match:

```
use List::Util 'first';
if (first { $_ eq $new_href } @m_href_array) { ... }
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils 'any';
if (any { $_ eq $new_href } @m_href_array) { ... }
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of searches, or your array is really long, you can make the process faster still by transforming the array into a hash, so you have O(1) lookups:

```
my %values_index;
@values_index{@array} = ();

if (exists $values_index{$element}) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regexp here. Just use `eq`:

```
grep { $_ eq $new_href } @m_href_array
```

Also it's a good idea to use hash instead of array for faster checking:

```
my %allready_used_url;

if ( $self->{_local} eq "true" && ! exists $allready_used_url{ $new_href } ) {
    $allready_used_url{ $new_href } = 1; ## add url to hash
    push( @m_href_array, $new_href );
    push( @href_array, $new_href );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the `?` in `$new_href?`?  Assuming there's a string in `$new_href`, do you expect the last letter of the string to be optional?  That's not how the RE parser reads it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value of `$new_herf` is `javascript:SearchGo(` which when substituted in the regex check looks like:

```
^javascript:SearchGo(?$
```

which is a broken regex as there is no matching `)` for `(`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the URL as the pattern, and it's not a valid pattern. That's not so bad because there are much better ways to do this. The smart match makes it almost trivial:

```
 use 5.010;

 if( $new_href ~~ @urls ) { ... }
```